# Is primary and replica shards sharing the load of the requests?

Tags: elasticsearch

For example in a cluster of 6 nodes, with 3 primary shards et 1 replica ...
Is the load of the queries shared over all the nodes?

[image]

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Yes. Any request that is sent to ES will be routed to one of the shards (primary or replica).
You can see in [detail](https://www.elastic.co/guide/en/elasticsearch/guide/current/distributed-search.html) How elastic search runs a query after any one of the nodes gets the search request.

Also [this](https://qbox.io/blog/optimizing-elasticsearch-how-many-shards-per-index) will give you an idea about how you can select how many shards are good for a particular scenario.

And just as you mentioned about having 6 nodes. If all those nodes are master + data (which is the default config) it is a bad idea to have even number of master nodes in ES. You can search for [split brain](http://blog.trifork.com/2013/10/24/how-to-avoid-the-split-brain-problem-in-elasticsearch/) issue of elasticsearch.

Comment: Having six data nodes is not a bad idea at all. The bad idea is to have an even number nodes of **master-eligible** nodes, but in the example above, we have no idea how many master-eligible nodes there are. If all nodes are master+data nodes, then yes, otherwise we cannot draw any conclusions solely based on the above schema.

Comment: @val Yes I missed that..have updated the answer. Thanks for the input.